NullPointerException on TextView inside onResume()
The flow of my code is onCreate(), onResume() and onPause(). I actually have 2 issues, but this is the most immediate of the two because it crashes my app.
onCreate():
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.append("placeholder");
    tv1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    //rest of the code dealing with files and sensors. tv1 not used.

onResume():
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv1); // Added to see if it helps with error. It doesn't.
    tv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    File folder = new File(getFilesDir()+ "/YYY");
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/XXX.txt");

    try
    {
        //some other file logic.
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            line = reader.readLine();
            tv.append(line); // ERROR HERE!
        }
        //Other irrelevant code here. Buffer closing stuff.
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO Read Error: "+e.toString());
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

onPause():
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("activity paused");
}

Error (indicated in comment in onResume()) text:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.surfacesmoothness1, PID: 19577
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.YYY/com.example.YYY.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:5219)
        at com.example.surfacesmoothness1.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I suspect it's a silly error but it escapes me at the moment. Maybe this is linked to my other issue - even when I use the emulator to go back to the main screen from the app (leave the app), the activity does not pass. I can still see all print/debug statements in onCreate() being printed to the console. But one thing at a time I guess.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="TEXT VIEW"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />


</LinearLayout>


In com.example.surfacesmoothness1.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:208) you're accessing a string length by calling android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:5219) via tv.append(line); where some string seems to be null, probably the line String. Make sure you check that String first, then build around it, as in simply not adding if null: if (line != null) tv.append(line);

You do reader.readLine() inside the while then append() without checking for null.

Maybe you have an operation order issue. You effectively discard the content of the first read when you read a line again. Reading might go beyond the content's end and the last read might return null, then the append is calling internally CharSequence.length().
Just do:
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    tv.append(line);
}


You're using "tv" in onResume instead of tv1 (assuming that tv1 is a global variable). So it should be
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        tv1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        File folder = new File(getFilesDir()+ "/YYY");
        File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/XXX.txt");
    
        try
        {
            //some other file logic.
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
                tv1.append(line);
            }
            //Other irrelevant code here. Buffer closing stuff.
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Read Error: "+e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Or
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        File folder = new File(getFilesDir()+ "/YYY");
        File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+"/XXX.txt");
    
        try
        {
            //some other file logic.
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
                tv.append(line); // ERROR HERE!
            }
            //Other irrelevant code here. Buffer closing stuff.
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("IO Read Error: "+e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

